# Roundcube Server Error Forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, email, imap, roundcube

I have installed roundcube mail on my web server on rackaspace cloud sites. It worked fined till today morning it just started popping up with the Server 403 Error.

The result in the ajax call comes as Invalid Request.

The only change i made was, i changed the timezone on there server to Sydney/Australia which is by default set to America because the server is located there.

Thanks

Comment: did you check the server logs to see if anything is listed as to why the error occurs? Does the error go away if you change timezones back? You've given almost no useful information to try to help solve this.

Comment: Yes i have checked the server error logs i get no logs in there.

Comment: And i had installed myroundcube plugin and installed the calendar but it worked fine for 2 days and today morning it crashed. I am running 0.8 Version or roundcube.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm digging up the deads, but it could help some people getting the same problem in the future. In my case (Debien Wheezy), it was a wrong setting (I don't know which one...) on my `php.ini` file. When I updated PHP and my config file was replaced with the one from Debian, everything suddenly went right.